# Why does gcc use stack area without decrementing stack pointer?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86-64, red-zone

For this simple C program,

```
int test(int a,int b)
{
    int k=89;
    return a+b;
}
int main()
{
    test(5,3);
}
```

gcc 10 produces the following assembly code (using https://godbolt.org/ and verified on my machine):

```
test:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-20], edi
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-24], esi
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 89
        mov     edx, DWORD PTR [rbp-20]
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-24]
        add     eax, edx
        pop     rbp
        ret
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     esi, 3
        mov     edi, 5
        call    test
        mov     eax, 0
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

As you can see, gcc is using stack area without decrementing stack pointer.
Is this normal? Isn't gcc supposed to decrement esp before using stack area?

Comment: It is changing the *base* pointer `rbp`.

Comment: `esp` yes, `rsp` no.  The 32-bit ABI doesn't have a red-zone.

Comment: @user207421: It's also changing RSP by using push/pop on RBP, but that's not what this question is asking about.  It's accessing space below the current RSP, via addressing modes like `[rbp-24]` while RBP = RSP.  (`-fomit-frame-pointer` is only enabled with optimization on, not at `-O0`, otherwise GCC would store `volatile` locals or other stuff it couldn't avoid spilling using addressing modes like `[rsp - 8]` and not waste instructions making / destroying a frame pointer.)